# The AdMob banners in my Corona game are not showing in the device when "testMode" is set to "false"

Tags: android, lua, admob, coronasdk

My problem is quite easy to understand. While developing my game (in Corona SDK), I followed all the steps necessary to implement the AdMob v2 ads in it, and of course I set the `testMode` parameter for the function `ads.show()` to `true` for testing the app. During the tests, all banners were showing as expected, and so were the interstitials. However, when I set `testMode`to `false`, the banners do not show anymore. The interstitials continue to work properly, the problem is with the banners only.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use emulators (although I have read many articles about this), so I have to test my app on a real device, and so I'm not able to watch for `print()` functions to see what's happening, but I created a test project with the following code on the `main.lua` file:

```
local ads = require("ads")
local t
local appID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx"

local function adListener(event)
    local msg = evento.response

    if event.phase == "loaded" then
    end

    if event.isError then
    end
end

ads.init("admob", appID, adListener)

background = display.newImage("Images/background.png", 0, 0)

local function showBanner()
    ads.show("banner", {x = 0, y = display.contentHeight/2, appID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx", testMode = false})
end

t = timer.performWithDelay(4000, showBanner, 1)
```

The background here is irrelevant. In this app, I used the same appID of my game's banners, and here the banners do appear on the screen. I wonder if my issue has something to do with the Composer API. One information that might be important is that I have not registered (uploaded) my game to the Play Store yet.

I woudn't be asking this question if I hadn't reasearched. I found a person with a similar problem in this link:  http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/50586-admob-banner-not-showing/

It seems there is still no concrete solution for this problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should put a print statement in your listener function to printout the event.response value (you seem to have a typo when assigning that to local variable called msg)

```
print( event.response )
```

then look in your device's console log while running your app on a device and see what messages you're getting from AdMob.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Rob. I tried to watch for messages using the `ddms` and `monitor` tools from the `Android SDK`, but it seems the print statement doesn't work. Fortunately, I found a "solution" some minutes ago. The problem was that, in my first scene, I was initializing the interstitial, so the only ads that would show in the app were them. So I changed this interstitial with a banner, and now the game shows them both, exactly how I wanted. I know this is not the best solution, but it works for now. If somebody comes with a better solution, I'll be waiting for it.